# Why did they say "You already have"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, expressions, do-support

I was watching *Banshee* and I couldn't understand why some guy used this phrase:

> A: I’m going to kill you. 
> B: You already have.

Why B didn't say "You already done" or "You already did" instead of "You already have"?

I could understand the meaning of the sentence but I couldn't understand why this is **<s>true</s> *correct*** to say this sentence.

Answer (score 3):

This is short for "You already have killed me." or "You have already done so."  To say "You already done" would not be correct. "You already did" would be correct, and in this context would have the exact same meaning, the difference is purely one of style.

Answer (score 0):

The verb "to kill" can mean figuratively

- ***[making someone work too hard](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=you%27re%20killing%20me)***
  or
- [***making someone laugh too much***](https://www.myenglishpages.com/site_php_files/random-idiom.php?c=1015#:%7E:text=The%20phrase%20you%27re%20killing,I%20almost%20died%20laughing.).
  or
- ***or driving crazy to know a secret*** (this riddle is killing me)

I have not seen the movie, so I don't know if your context is negative or positive. Just looking at the sentence, the first character is clearly threatening the second (though not necessarily with real death - people can say "I am going to kill you" just when they are really angry with someone). The second character turns it into a joke, and uses another meaning of the verb "to kill".

So, if the context were positive (with no intention of real killing), your sentence may mean something like

> I am going to make you pay for this! (or I am going to make it hard for you)
>
> You have already [annoyed me to death](https://nancydepcik.com/does-someone-annoy-you-to-death/)/gotten on my nerves/harmed me.

Comment: There's nothing in the sentence or the context to suggest the 'kill' is used in a figurative or joking context. The connotation here is not the same as someone saying, 'You're killing me,' in a lighthearted way as if to say, 'You're making me laugh,' or 'You're tiring me out.'

Comment: I did mention that I do not know the context of the movie. There is nothing in the sentence to suggest that "kill" is not used in a figurative way either.

Comment: No, there's not. However, the connotation of the word 'kill' that means to make someone laugh or make someone work hard is not used by the person who is making the other person laugh or work hard. It's only used by the person who is laughing or working hard. When someone says, 'I'm going to kill you', they never mean, "I'm going to make you laugh." The phrase, 'You're killing me' is idiomatic and only used by the person who is laughing or working hard.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. I see that my answer needs editing.